# How to remove some certain column in multiple files in R?

Tags: r

everyone. I want to remove some certain columns in multiple files(csv.).
for example, I have 50 files. And I want to delete a,b,c column in every file.

The point is I don't know how to get the files. Save the change in every single file and remain the original file name.

```
 library(tidyverse)
 # I want to delet some column which contain messy code
 # input a list of file
 df <- list.files(here("Data"),pattern=".csv",full.names = TRUE) %>%
   lapply(read_csv) %>%     #read csv
   lapply(subset,select = -c(a,b,c)) #To remove the messy code
   write.csv(df, file = here()) 
 # I want to save the change in the original files, but I don't know how to do it.
```

Comment: Would a Bash solution be acceptable? Also, are columns a, b, c always at the same position?

Comment: @Stijn Could you give me more detail about Bash solution? And yes, they are always at the same position

Comment: Well, I don't know if you're working in a Linux environment, but if you did then deleting columns from csv files would be quite easy. An example can be found [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-remove-columns-from-csv-based-on-column-number-using-bash-shell).

Answer (score 0):

Read all the files (if all the files are in the working directory) directly into a list and process it.

```
 files <- list.files() #if you want to read all the files in working directory
 lst2 <- lapply(files, function(x) read.table(x, header=TRUE))
 lapply(lst2,`[`,c(-a,-b,-c)
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to write the output? I mean just save the changes in each file and also keep the same file name.

Comment: No need for two `lapply` calls, extend the anonymous function to `read.table`, subset with `[`, then `write.table` with same *x* name.